# OWASP ZAP: How to Test on AWS + Magento? Which guidelines must be observed?

Tags: penetration-test, aws

I am supposed to do a test for AWS. But since AWS has limitations, probably also in the direction of DDoS and other points, what does a corresponding test scenario look like?

It is about a Magento instance that is integrated on AWS.

Do you already have some knowledge on how I could proceed best?

Is there a test profile that I could use, or an OWASP script that I can integrate?

Comment: and you've read this: https://aws.amazon.com/security/penetration-testing/ ?

Comment: This more or less boils down to "what does AWS allow (which is governed by the ToS), "how do I use OWASP ZAP?" (Which is too broad), and "can you recommend some resources?" Which is off topic.

Comment: This is not true, because what AWS allows is one question, what Magento allows is another. The same is true if OWASP Zap has a profile that allows a direct selection of the allowed points. So no off-topic!

Comment: @Mornon you misread his comment. "can you recommend some resources?" is off-topic. You seem to be asking "is there a pre-made ZAP profile that perfectly meets my needs?"

Comment: Yes that is the goal, whether there is a prefabricated setting for ZAP.

Answer (score 2):

From [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/security/penetration-testing/) as of today:

> AWS customers are welcome to carry out security assessments or penetration tests against their AWS infrastructure without prior approval for 8 services, listed in the next section under “Permitted Services.”
>
> Please ensure that these activities are aligned with the policy set
> out below. Note: Customers are not permitted to conduct any security
> assessments of AWS infrastructure, or the AWS services themselves. If
> you discover a security issue within any AWS services in the course of
> your security assessment, please contact AWS Security immediately.
>
> If AWS receives an abuse report for activities related to your
> security testing, we will forward it to you. When responding, please
> provide the root cause of the reported activity, and detail what
> you’ve done to prevent the reported issue from recurring. Learn more
> here.
>
> Resellers of AWS services are responsible for their customer’s
> security testing activity.

Currently you don't need authorization from AWS for the following services:

- Amazon EC2 instances, NAT Gateways, and Elastic Load Balancers
- Amazon RDS
- Amazon CloudFront
- Amazon Aurora
- Amazon API Gateways
- AWS Lambda and Lambda Edge functions
- Amazon Lightsail resources
- Amazon Elastic Beanstalk environments

Those activities are prohibited:

- DNS zone walking via Amazon Route 53 Hosted Zones
- Denial of Service (DoS), Distributed Denial of Service (DDoS), Simulated DoS, Simulated DDoS (These are subject to the DDoS Simulation Testing policy)
- Port flooding
- Protocol flooding
- Request flooding (login request flooding, API request flooding)

I don't have any recommendation on how to test Magento with ZAP but I think you should focus on custom development that might have been done on this shop. Also make sure to check the version and verify that Magento is up to date.

Comment: A really good answer. 

Do you have any idea if the points you mentioned in OWASP can somehow already be issued? Do you mean the points to be excluded? 

Is there a ready-made profile for AWS and Magento testing?